# Querying multiple indices but limit the results from a single index - Elasticsearch 6.x

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

All, I am using ES 6.7 and trying to return the results from a single index while querying two indices( **customer, payment**) and doing a terms lookup against **user-customers** index. The index I want data from(**customer**) has more fields than the second index. But for some reason, I only see results from the payment index. The fields **customerName**, **customerNumber**, **state**, **address** only exist on customer index. But I only want customers that has **totalCredits > 0**(This exists only on **payment** index) ordered by the logic in the sort array. I tried adding an **_index** filter( setting this to customer) but dint help. Adding source filtering doesn't help either. Is this doable in **ES 6.7**?. Am I left with the option of adding the fields in the sort array to the payment index or are there some other options?

ES query

```
GET customer,payment/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "customerName": {
        "order": "asc",
        "unmapped_type": "keyword"
      }
    },
    {
      "customerNumber": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "state": {
        "order": "asc",
        "unmapped_type": "keyword"
      }
    },
    {
      "address": {
        "order": "asc",
        "unmapped_type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "status": [
                    "pending"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "customerNumber": {
              "index": "user-customers",
              "type": "_doc",
              "id": "rennish@emial.com",
              "path": "users"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "totalCredits": {
              "gt": 0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your query cannot be running as it is not well-formed. The `sort` section must be located at the top-level, i.e. not inside `query`... so something's wrong there already.

Comment: @Val, my bad. I din't double check when I edited the query. This is formatted correctly. This is the query I am having issues with.